# Iterate through nested map

Tags: java

I have a nested hashmap (Hashmap inside a hashmap).

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> test = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String,String> testMp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    testMp.put("1", "Key1");
    testMp.put("2", "Key2");
    testMp.put("3", "Key3");
    testMp.put("4", "Key4");
    testMp.put("5", "Key4");
    test.put("One", testMp);
```

Ideally if I need to print the key and the values in the test map, I'd do this -

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String,String>> t:test.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("KEY: " +t.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +t.getValue());
}
```

But I want the key and the value of the inner map as well. I want something like this -

```
Key of outermap
    Key of innermap, and its value.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then do a nested loop :

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String,String>> t:test.entrySet()) {
   String key = t.getKey();
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : t.getValue().entrySet())
     System.out.println("OuterKey: " + key + " InnerKey: " + e.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +e.getValue());
}
```

or

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String,String>> t:test.entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(t.getKey());
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> e : t.getValue().entrySet())
     System.out.println("KEY: " + e.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +e.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a recursive method which will call itself when it encounters that the entry to corresponding key is a map.